# Aggregate Rating Rich snippets for Google

Tags: rich-snippets

[VroomVroomVroom](http://www.vroomvroomvroom.com.au/)

At above link you can see something like: **Rating: 4.5/5 based on 5 reviews of 10 votes.**

After reading specs i know that Aggregate rating require atleast 1 of RatingCount or ReviewCount. But, my question is that: Can i show something like: **Rating: 4.5/5 based on 10 reviews.** Here 10 is RatingCount, but I am using reviews keyword. I am asking this because i don't want the site to get penalized by Google. Also, I shall always be showing latest 5-10 reviews in scrolling fashion.
FYI: I am using microdata style of Rich-snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and talking to SEO guys, I found that its permissible to change text as we require. Only Meta tags should be correct.